# piece of php code for prevent hacking

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a php file at my site, and I connect to db, get some records and list them in same file.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "blabla", "blabla") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("blabla") or die(mysql_error());

$blabla1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_cat=1");
$blabla2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_cat=2");
$blabla3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_cat=3");
```

So, is there anything I need to do for security? Like sql-injection or anything else. there is nothing going to url. It is just `www.blabla.com/gallery.php`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This snippet is perfectly safe, because there are no variables put into the query string.

To work safely in case you have to deal with variables one day - be they directly coming in from the user, or from another data source - you may want to switch over to a mySQL library that supports parametrized queries, like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Those eliminate the danger of injections completely, because they take care of escaping the incoming data automatically.

If you stick with the `mysql_*` functions, make sure you escape <strike>all incoming</strike> any data using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) *and* ensure they are inserted within a pair of single quotes.

Comment: You continue to repeat the same error again and again. not incoming data but any data.

Comment: not any data but only data that going to be enclosed in quotes :) It is simple rules but everyone keep forgetting some part of it. That's why unconditional use of parametrized queries considered better practice.

Answer (score 4):

As long as your queries don't use parameters, SQL Injection is not a risk. 
SQL Injection can only happen when the users (or other sources) can influence anything that is send to the database in SQL, for example searchwords

Comment: Actually SQL Injection can only happen when the **programmer** fail to follow simple syntax rules. And SQL injections has nothing to do with user unput

Comment: How would you perform a sql injection without userinput?

Comment: @Col. Schrapnel: A developer should always sanatize any parameters before using it in a query. It is true that the data can also come from a other source (eg. a file on the hard disk)

Comment: but the data on the disk is safe too as long it has never been provided by the user or has been generated from user input

Comment: @Patrick Cornelissen: It could also be a connection with a other application for all that matters. Never trust anything that you don't have full control over. A file on the disk could also be corrupted by a virus or by a other program

Comment: Look @Patrick 1. special characters escaping is not an injection protection issue. It is general syntax rule. 2. As Jasper mentioned, there can be other source of data.

Comment: @Patrick "as long it has never been provided by the user" how do you know? Why to guess at all? Anyway, not-malicious-data from disk can contain apostrophes. I don't think you want your query to be broken. mysql escaping is not injection protection but a syntax rule and must be used unconditionally, no matter of data source

Comment: Almost all data on discs has been created from or in direct relation to user input, so it's almost always necessary to escape or even better use prepared statements. You don't need to do it when for example you read only database IDs or you have the data strongly typed (for example as int) in your programming language. Then it's pretty unlikely to be able to inject something.

I don't want to advocate to build SQL on your own, I even intended to advocate the use of prepared statements because almost everything has been user input in some way, that's why I wrote that in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are no security issues here. SQL injection might happen where you get input from the user and use it in your queries.

Answer (score 2):

if gallery table contain some user input, then some XSS attack may be conducted. To prevent this, all untrusted user input must be prepared using `htmlspecialchars()` function before printing to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is safe, as there is no user provided input in the queries.

if you have userinput, for example by getting the category that should be displayed from the URL or from POST you should use prepared statements. this may you are safe even with user input. This is much safer than pure escaping because the sql is parsed and then the parameters are inserted. This is better for performance and the userinput can't change the structure of the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you might want to consider, assuming that the connection code is in the web-accessible PHP script, is to either:

1. move the MySQL connection out of the
   script and into a file outside of
   the site's document root
2. or, use externally-sourced variables
   (i.e. from a different file outside
   of the document root) for the
   username and password in place of
   hard-coded details in the script

That way if, for whatever reason the server displays the code instead of rendering the PHP, then the details will remain safe from view